# WCF: Programmatic Setting Endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to programmatic set the end point for a WCF connection.

I have not been able to, below is the code I am using code someone help identify what is wrong?

```
        Uri wsBaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:27198/");

        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceClient), wsBaseAddress);

        WSHttpBinding wshttpbinding = new WSHttpBinding();

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), wshttpbinding, "ServiceClient");
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), wshttpbinding,
           "http://localhost:27198/Service.svc");

        host.Open();
```

**EDIT:**

> Error: HTTP could not register URL "http://+:27198/" because TCP port
>   27198 is being used by another application."

Thank you

Comment: What is not working?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @cadrell0 sorry see my edit. I dont really understand why the error is happening.

Answer (score 1):

> HTTP could not register URL "http://+:27198/" because TCP port 27198 is being used by another application."

This pretty much says it all. There is another application that is currently listening on that port, and since only one application can bind to a given port and IP at a given moment, your program can't.

Execute `netstat -abn` in `cmd` to see which program that is, most probable the ASP.NET Development Server.

If no other program is bound to that port, you can try running Visual Studio as administrator.

Comment: but that is the same address that was in my client app.config how was it able to work before?

Comment: @user101010101  Check maybe your client app is currently run and listening that port and you try to start second instance.

Answer (score 0):

The statement below you are not providing the service name though it is not used in last statement with adding endpoint

```
 Uri wsBaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:27198/");
```

it should be

```
 Uri wsBaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:27198/Service");
```

You have to provide the service name instead of service file name with extension

Change

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), wshttpbinding,
           "http://localhost:27198/Service.svc");
```

to

```
 host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), wshttpbinding,
           "http://localhost:27198/Service");
```

Comment: what error you get, is you service running? where you hosted service?

Comment: {"HTTP could not register URL http://+:27198/Service/ because TCP port 27198 is being used by another application."}. Is the same error as before. It is hosted on my local machine and yes I checked the service is running.

Comment: The service is already registered go you web.config and find the url there with same port if it is there then remove the service from there